# Cómo corregir el error Clase no registrada en una macro en Excel?

Tags: vb.net, excel

Estoy trabajando con una macro en excel, la problematica que tengo es que cuando lo exporto localmente no tengo ningún problema el problema surge cuando subo mi documento al servidor (que es somee) y ahi me manda este error,

`80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`,

he probado con las librerias y en el tipo de versión a la hora de exportarlo, el documento lo tengo de una carpeta que se llama "documentos" y esa obviamente esta arriba en el host, solo tengo problemas arriba en el servidor, les dejo mi codigo, espero puedan ayudarme ya que estoy un poco atorado con este problema, gracias.

```
var aplicacion = new Excel.Application();
            aplicacion.Visible = true;

            Excel.Workbooks libro = aplicacion.Workbooks;

            /********ESTO ES PARA ABRIR EL ARCHIVO DE NOMINA*********/

            Excel.Workbook sheet = libro.Open(Server.MapPath("~/documentos/PagoNomina.xls"), ReadOnly: false, Editable: true);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)sheet.ActiveSheet;

            for (int i = 0; i < gridcontra.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < gridcontra.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    oSheet.Cells[i + 8, j + 4] = Convert.ToString(gridcontra.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text).ToUpper();
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < gridcontra.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                oSheet.Cells[8 + i, 3] = i + 1;
            }
```

Comment: No entiendo qué tienen que ver C#, asp.net y virtualhost con esta pregunta. ¿Nos explicas, por favor?

Comment: perdón, es la primera pregunta que hago y apenas lo voy dominando, el programa lo estoy haciendo en c#, esta programado en visual studio y pues lo subi a un host